# Why is the "files" property of my AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post

I am trying to to a post through C# to a controller, but despite the code jumping to where it should, the "files" property of my Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection is totally empty.

Here is the code that is getting sent via POST

```
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = Path.GetFileName(FileName)
    };
    content.Add(fileContent, "file", FileName);

    var requestUri = "http://localhost:5000/api/XXXX";
    var result = client.PostAsync(requestUri, content).Result;
}
```

Which leads to no files coming through

[image]

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my code about upload files. Try `https://localhost:port/upload` for  test.
[image]

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
      
    [HttpPost("fileApi")]
    public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        var a = file;
        // code responsible for file processing
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("upload")]
    public async Task UploadSampleFile()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("E:\\test.txt"); //prepare a file
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://localhost:7210/fileApi"); //change to your port
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            { new StreamContent(stream), "file", "Test.txt" }
        };
        request.Content = content;
        await client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used parts of this code in combination with my own, and I found that clearly one of the lines I was dunning was causing the issue. In particular, the forth line down seemed to be the major cause.

Thanks for your code example, it really helped clear things up!